# What is a real world product or development board that uses a recent Arm Cortex-R based chip and what is its clock speed? Name anything

Tags: arm

tl;dr: There does not exist anything with a Cortex-R8 CPU in it. **Prove me wrong.**

What is a piece of hardware that has a chip inside implementing a Cortex-R8* (introduced in 2016) (or, failing that, the Cortex-R7*, introduced in 2011, or an even earlier Cortex-R) core? (Dates taken from the [Wikipedia page about the Cortex-R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-R))
What is its clock speed?

For the same question regarding the Cortex-M0+ an answer would be the [Raspberry Pi Pico](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-pico/specifications/), clocked at 125MHz.
For the Cortex-A8 an answer would be the [BeagleBone Black](https://beagleboard.org/black), clocked at 1GHz.

It does not have to be a development or microcontroller board, I would be happy to learn about anything that uses a Cortex-R8/7*. So far I have not found a single one.

Comment: @Higemaru: The Cortex-R82 as example is still in beta phase and will be released in this year. Here the full question on [ARM Developer Community](https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/soc-design-and-simulation-forum/49727/is-cortex-r82-fast-model-available/175095#175095) with answer (2 months old).

Comment: I think, it's better for other (released) processor models and available development boards to ask this question directly on [ARM Developer Commuinty](https://community.arm.com/).